MongoDB ReplicaSet system configuration and modeling
I want to create a replica set model that look like this:
PC 1 : ip=1.1.1.1 - The only one that writes
PC 2 : ip=2.2.2.2 - Read only
PC 3 : ip=3.3.3.3 - Read only

Use-case: On PC 1 I have a program that writes to the DB, on PC 2 and 3 I have a program that reads that data, I want to be able to access the data from each PC even if there is no connection. The solution I thought of is - creating a replica-set, that way data is replicated to each pc locally, the challenge is how to configure the replica set.
System requirements: Only pc 1 does the writing - meaning this is the primary If connection between the PC’s falls each PC should be able to work as stand alone, as far as I understand the solution for that is nominating that PC as primary therefore an arbiter is needed (you need a group of minimum 2 to do an election) - based on this requirement, each pc runs a DB instance and an arbiter. And this should look something like this:
members: [
  {_id:0,host:“1.1.1.1:27017”,priority:10},      
  {_id:1,host:“1.1.1.1:27018”,arbiterOnly: true},
  {_id:2,host:“2.2.2.2:27017”,priority:1},
  {_id:3,host:“2.2.2.2:27018”,arbiterOnly: true},
  {_id:4,host:“3.3.3.3:27017”,priority:1},
  {_id:5,host:“3.3.3.3:27018”,arbiterOnly: true}
]

I have tested this scenario and closed PC1 and PC2 therefore PC3 has left alone; on PC3 the DB instance and arbiter are running, for some reason the instance on PC3 won’t become primary (meaning I cant access the DB and read). I would love knowing why.
Maybe this is the problem?
{“setDefaultRWConcern”: 1,“defaultWriteConcern”: { “w”: 2 },“defaultReadConcern”: { “level”: “majority” }}


If the connection fails, you expect each instance to become a primary and basically have three independent primary instances? And once network services resume, you expect them all to form a cluster again and re-sync?

Maybe read also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658590/mongoclient-to-connect-to-multiple-hosts-to-handle-failover/69666511#69666511

@deceze no, I expect each instance to remain secondary for local reads, and only the one with priority 10 to remain primary.

Your assumption is wrong. The majority of all members must be available in order to elect a primary. An arbiter (one arbiter) is useful when you have an even number members, e.g. 1 out of 2 is not the majority, thus you add an arbiter.
Member combination could be like this:
members: [
  {_id:0, host:"1.1.1.1:27017", priority:10},      
  {_id:1, host:"2.2.2.2:27017", priority:0, votes:0},
  {_id:2, host:"3.3.3.3:27017", priority:0, votes:0}
]

However, I don't see any reason to do this. If host 1.1.1.1 goes down, then your application turns into read/only mode. Why are you doing this? Make them as normal secondary (e.g. priority:1, votes:1) then your application remains fully up and running even if on host goes down.
You can still read from secondaries if you prefer. Just define it in the connection string.
Some more information:

It is pointless to have more than one Arbiter. In recent version of MongoDB it is by default even not possible to configure multiple Arbiters. With three hosts there is no reason to have any Arbiter at all
When you shutdown PC1 and PC2 then 4 out of 6 members are not available. That's not the majority. No majority -> no Primary - period!
You cannot control by replica set configurations from which member the data is read. You can define this only at the client connection. If you like to control it more granular then just primary/secondary, then you have to work with Replica Set Tag Sets but for only three members it does not make much sense.
You lose a lot of availability when you force only PC1 being PRIMARY. Use the very standard 3-member Replica set. Usually you don't care at all which one is the actual primary. Maybe give higher priority on PC1 if you really like.


I have a requirement to replicate the data stored by PC1 to all other PC's, but there could be a moment where PC2 or PC3 disconnects the network and I want to keep the DB on that PC available for local reading. In other words, lets say I have an application on PC 3 that reads from its local DB, if PC3 disconnects the network, the DB should be still running, but if its part of a ReplicaSet and doesn't have a majority running the state of that DB is down.

Maybe ReplicaSet is not suitable here, because I need it only for replicating the data written by PC1, and its nice that its automatic and handles fast forwarding if any PC was down and writes have been made.

I really don't get your problem. If PC3 disconnects then your application is not affected at at. How do you connect tp the database? If PC3 is not reachable then the client will automatically read from PC2. And of course you can read locally from PC3. Where is your issue?
